# How to make ImageView transition from Activity to Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using ScrollView to show 10 newest images. After click on specific element, I want to start new activity with ViewPager, where are all details of that 10 newest images, and there should be transition between small image and big image. But it shows only exit transition of neighbour element in ViewPager. Can you help me please?

Code:

```
//shared element has transitionName in XML
//this is how i start activity of ViewPager
ActivityOptions transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, v, trans.getName());
startActivity(i, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());

//setup ViewPager in started Activity
ViewPager myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.postsViewPager);
PostViewPager avp = new PostViewPager(getSupportFragmentManager(), postEntities);
myViewPager.setAdapter(avp);

//every Fragment in ViewPager has set up transitionName programatically in onCreateView
final ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView14);
iv.setTransitionName("changing"
```